# Расширение для PHP с помощью SWIG: определение классов и функций

Tags: swig, php, c++

Доброго времени суток.

Хочу накалякать с помощью SWIG-а расширение для PHP. Проект на C++ + SWIG + PHP.
Все бы хорошо, но функции и классы отказываются нормально кушаться компилятором & swig-ом.

Собственно, простяцкий пример:

Как компилю:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm ext_wrap.cpp
rm ext_wrap.o
rm example.so

swig -c++ -php ext.i

gcc `php-config --includes` -fpic -c ext_wrap.cpp
gcc -shared ext_wrap.o -o example.so

cp example.so /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/
```

Далее - смотрим ext.i

```
    %module smcsql

//class smcsql {
//      pubic:
//              smcsql();
//              ~smcsql();
//};

extern char* getDev();
char *getDev() {
        return "\r\nКомар Станислав\r\n";
};

//extern char* getDev();
```

Итого получаю следующую ошибку:

```
EXPERIMENTAL # ./compile.sh 
ext_wrap.cpp: In function ‘void _wrap_getDev(int, zval*, zval**, zval*, int)’:
ext_wrap.cpp:1101:27: error: ‘getDev’ was not declared in this scope
```

Может, кто уже сталкивался, в курсе, что за шляпа происходит :) Судя по офф доке SWIG-а, все делаю правильно.

Comment: Похоже, что-то с текстом самой библиотеки

Comment: Какой именно библиотеки ? :)

Comment: Которую Вы пишите: example.so :)

Comment: я на девственном си пишу, проблем никогда не возникало, выбрал именно си т.к. для php он родной чем кресты

Comment: Не совпадение параметров getdev. Что-то с оберткой не так. Покажите строку 1101:27, на которую ругается. Интересная тема. Сам хочу на с++ и пхп писать.